# How to use django-google-cloud-storage for GCS in Django on GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, django-storage

How do I use a Django Custom Storage backend with Google Cloud Storage?

Trying to use this: [ckopanos's django-google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/ckopanos/django-google-cloud-storage)

As per the documentation I have added the following to my 'settings.py':

```
GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET = [my bucket name] # the name of the bucket you have created from the google cloud storage console
GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_URL = [my bucket URL] #whatever the url for accessing your cloud storgage bucket
GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_DEFAULT_CACHE_CONTROL = [cache control] # default cache control headers for your files

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'google.storage.googleCloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
```

And I added the 'google' folder/package to my project files so it should be accesible for 'settings.py'

**How do I use this Custom Storage System in my views now?**

I can manually use gcs by doing the following (this example stores an xlsx on gcs):

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
import xlsxwriter
import StringIO

bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',
                           app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
bucket = '/' + bucket_name

filename = bucket + '/'+ userid + '/' + [some code] + '.xlsx' 
gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
            'w',
            content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            options={'x-goog-meta-user': userid})

output = StringIO.StringIO()
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory': True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello World')

# Close the workbook before streaming the data.
workbook.close()

# Rewind the buffer.
output.seek(0)            

gcs_file.write(output.read())
gcs_file.close()
```

**How do I import the storage system for use in my views? Would you reccomend a different storage system for Django and GCS instead?**

Comment: Recommended by whom? For what purpose?

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase. What is the easiest way, or easiest to implement package (that is still maintained), to connect Django with Cloud Storage? Without needing to write my own custom storage system. (I.e. is there a "plug and play" package that I can use that is maintained, and that works with little development overhead). Purpose is to: upload xlsx, xls, and csv files from multiple users to gcs, and to allow private downloads of these same files (restricted only to the user that uploaded the file).

Comment: Finding a package is explicitly off-topic, easiest way likely too opinion-based. Please see [ask].

Comment: Alright, I have made the question more specific, to a specific package I have been trying to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the way you would use any other File Storage System in Django, because custom storage backends in Django are built by defining a custom storage class which must be a [subclass of `django.core.files.storage.Storage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-file-storage/).

[django-cloud-storage](https://github.com/ckopanos/django-google-cloud-storage) , is a custom storage backend which allows you to use GCS in Django, just like you would if you were using any other storage backend.

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'google.storage.googleCloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
```

The above line in your settings.py makes GCS your default File storage system.
That means if you define a new `FileField` in your `models`, it will use Google Cloud Storage.

You can use it in your views like this:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
file = default_storage.open(file_name, 'w')
file.write(output.read())
file.close()
```

The file will be saved to your default bucket.

Comment: Thanks, that is how I ended up using it. I was getting confused because while reading the documentation it seemed to imply that if you imported 'default_storage' with `from django.core.files.storage import default_storage` that it would import _Django's_ default storage system (file system storage) and not your settings.py defined DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE system.