# Upload images to google cloud storage using django views

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am creating a django application in hosted in google cloud. I am able to send and save data in the backend mysql database but not able to upload and save images using django's ImageField.

Please help. Any ideas

I am using django_google_cloud_storage as mentioned in https://github.com/ckopanos/django-google-cloud-storage. 
But i am getting ImportError: cannot import name googleCloud. 
Do i need to include google and cloudstorage in installed_apps section of the settings?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Are you encountering any error? What is happening? *`"not able to upload and save images"`* is not clear enough.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please i really need help on this

Comment: Post the full error traceback.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to solve my problem by using the django-googgle-cloud-storage library and using the instructions in https://libraries.io/pypi/django-google-cloud-storage and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451440/how-to-use-django-google-cloud-storage-for-gcs-in-django-on-gae links.